# how to get openlayers 2 tile url from OSM layer

Tags: openlayers

I need to get the tile url for the tile under the mouse cursor so I can show a magnified version of this image in a box. I agree that this is much easier to do in OL3, but for this application I have to use OL2.  I've found snippets that calculate the url ([taken from here](https://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/UsingCustomTiles)):

```
    function get_my_url (bounds) {
    var res = this.map.getResolution();
    var x = Math.round ((bounds.left - this.maxExtent.left) / (res * this.tileSize.w));
    var y = Math.round ((this.maxExtent.top - bounds.top) / (res * this.tileSize.h));
    var z = this.map.getZoom();

    var path = z + "/" + x + "/" + y + "." + this.type; 
    var url = this.url;
    if (url instanceof Array) {
        url = this.selectUrl(path, url);
    }
    return url + path;

}
```

However, as I understand it's use, this function is called from the layer definition.  I can't find any examples of how this type of function can be called either on mouse hover or mouse click on a tile.

I'm guessing that "this" in the snippet above is the tile.  How can I get the tile to pass it to this function? There is no getTile function.  Is there an easier way to go about getting the tile url? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

With 'lonLat' as the point clicked or overed, and 'layer' a reference to the OSM layer:

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(lonLat.lon, lonLat.lat, lonLat.lon, lonLat.lat);
var xyz = layer.getXYZ(bounds);
var tileUrl = OpenLayers.String.format(layer.url[0], xyz);
```

The same should work also for non-OSM layers that extends OpenLayers.Layer.XYZ